# How can I make gulp-watch generate CSS file when SASS changes?

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp-watch, node-sass

Here is my code:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./public/stylesheets/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/stylesheets/'));
});

gulp.task('watch-saas', function () {
    watch('./public/stylesheets/*.scss', function () {
        gulp.start('sass');
    });
});
```

Output:

```
[19:15:46] Using gulpfile ~/WebstormProjects/mySite/gulpFile.js
[19:15:46] Starting 'watch-saas'...
[19:15:46] Finished 'watch-saas' after 38 ms
```

Im afraid no CSS. Any ideas how to make this work?

I think my code looks very much like the example code [here](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/docs/readme.md#starting-tasks-on-events). And the 'sass' task runs fine on its own.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not that experienced in Gulp, but I usually use:

```js
gulp.task('watch-saas', function () {
    return gulp.watch(['./public/stylesheets/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});
```

I assume that you have to return the result in your task, because it's an asynchronous task.

Comment: This is using gulp-watch and not gulp.watch. Doesn't appear to help though although it does stop the 'Finished' message from appearing.

Comment: Incidentally your code doesn't work either. Perhaps there's something wrong with my setup.

Comment: Seems that it does work after all. Problem was that I'm running it from Webstorm and I think I've been misunderstanding when auto save takes place.

Answer (score 0):

> We should first pipe it and ask gulp to watch it in changes in our scss or file we alerted

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return  gulp.src(''./public/stylesheets/.scss'').pipe(gulp.dest('./sass'));  
});

watch('./public/stylesheets/.scss', function(){
    gulp.start('styles');
 });
```

**styles** is the task name which I assigned here